# Capistrano 3 Permission Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm converting an app from capistrano version 2 to version 3 and now i'm getting this error:

```
DEBUG [7095ead3] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@myapp.git.beanstalkapp.com:/myapp/myapp.git on myapp.com
DEBUG [7095ead3] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/myapp.com/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@myapp.git.beanstalkapp.com:/myapp/myapp.git )
DEBUG [7095ead3]        fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/myapp.com/git-ssh.sh': Permission denied
DEBUG [7095ead3]        fatal: unable to fork
DEBUG [7095ead3] Finished in 0.195 seconds with exit status 128 (failed).
```

How can i get past this?

Comment: Are you able to clone the app directly into the server with capistrano? please check that option as it may seem that there is a possible error in the .ssh config

Comment: Yea you're right, I can't actually run the command from the server. Is this something new that never used to be done in capistrano 2? Like did cap 2 checkout code locally and then push it to the server?

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I shouldn't necessarily be able to run that command on the server because when I run it on my dev machine, I have the option `forward_agent: true` set which passes my credentials (including keys) to the server when running the command.

Comment: I can see your GIT_SSH is trying to make a clone in /tmp, im not sure if executables and scripts are allowed on your server /tmp, can you create your tmp directory in your /home/<user> and see if that helps..

Comment: I can, but how can I modify the capistrano task so that it knows to use the tmp dir I specify?

Comment: You can set your deploy.rb: set :tmp_dir, "#{fetch(:home)}/tmp"

Comment: I added tmp_dir like you said and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you able to clone into the newly created temp dir?

Comment: I should clarify. I added tmp_dir like you said, but I'm not explicitly setting the `:home` variable anywhere. Is that an implicit variable?

Comment: This might be helpful https://community.webfaction.com/questions/15144/capistrano-3-deploys-fatal-error-executing-tmpmyappgit-sshsh

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this problem and solved this by reading this website (https://community.webfaction.com/questions/15144/capistrano-3-deploys-fatal-error-executing-tmpmyappgit-sshsh)

So, this is what I attempted

- Create tmp dir in your HOME directory
- I added in my .bashrc

  export TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp"
- In deploy.rb, add this

  set :tmp_dir, "#{fetch(:home)}/tmp"

Then, try to cap production deploy again and it worked for me, hopefully for you too! :D

Comment: Why is it necessary to add a TMPDIR variable in your .bashrc?

Comment: For some reasons `fetch(:home)` doesn't work for me. In my config it made sense to use `fetch(:stage)` instead, which I did.

Comment: I had to set home as well: 
`set :home, '/home/mysite'`
`set :tmp_dir, "#{fetch(:home)}/tmp"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug inside Capistrano. You have to remove whitespaces from your :application variable.

Check here for more:
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/778